# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, .net-framework-version

My App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I was facing the below error when I was trying to download some `.pdf` file from a url.

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader
>   Detail=CR must be followed by LF

After extensive research, most of the suggestions are to add `useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"` in config file, but unfortunately it was already present in my config file.

But I realized that, all the examples in suggested solutions are not having this particular line

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
```

So I went ahead and removed and tried to download the `.pdf` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

and it **worked**. My application is built using **.Net Framework 4**

What I am trying to understand is there any impact of removing this line, or it can fixed in some other way ?

Comment: What happens if you remove them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, removing the line, wouldn't not "break" anything.  That line just target the .NET framework 4.0 directly in your application.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/886256/NET-versioning-and-multi-targeting-on-Csharp-appli

Here is a good and lengthy code project file I came across last year December when converting some of my projects and cleaning out some "useless" code from files

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, will go through the link. Do you have any idea why that line is causing the error or I have to use different attributes ?

Comment: You can try this

It may be because of the \r\n you have inside of your Content-Type header. The charset should be part of the Content-Type header line.

Also if absolutely necessary to use multiline (in this case it isn't), you can move the space to the correct place: char *message = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/xml;\r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"